# Proof that $N^\frac{1}{N}\leq C$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

How can I prove that $$N^\frac{1}{N}\leq C,\;\forall N\geq 1?$$I suppose $C=2$. I think induction works by I am not sure of how to proceed after checking for $N=1$.

Comment: Can you show $N\le 2^N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction to show the equivalent statement $N \le 2^N$:

Base: $2\le 2^2$

Step: Assume for N, and prove for $N+1$ that $N+1\le 2^{N+1}$, which is:
$$N+1 \le2^N+1\le 2\cdot2^N=2^{N+1}$$ Which is true for all $N \ge2$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$N^{\frac 1 N}=e^{\frac{\log N}{N}}\to 1$$
so the sequence  $\left(N^{\frac 1 N}\right)_N$ is convergent then it's bounded hence there's $C$ such that
$$N^{\frac 1 N}\le C,\quad \forall N\ge 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n = n^{1/n} - 1$. Then $n = (1+a_n)^n \ge n a_n$ so that $a_n \le 1$.